# Getting Compile Error for opencv 2.4.3

Tags: c++, opencv

I met a compile error in this line, saying that png_libpng_version_1_5_9 is not defined.

```
/* Generate a compiler error if there is an old png.h in the search path. */
typedef png_libpng_version_1_5_9 Your_png_h_is_not_version_1_5_9;
```

Does anyone meet the same problem?

I downloaded opencv 2.4.3 from http://opencv.org/opencv-2-4-3-released.html

The lines are `1819-1820` from `3rdparty/libpng/pngtest.c`.

Comment: I passed the compilation by commenting that sentence...I just wonder why I got this line of code?

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, could you precise which file and which line the code is from ?

Comment: @SirDarius Updated. Do you know why do they add these lines of code?

Comment: probably to ensure that the installed version of libpng is 1.5.9. With all due respect to libpng developers, this looks hackish at best...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the comment before that line of code is quite clear.  If there is already `png.h` on your path, then calls to `png.h` might go to the wrong set of code.

To ensure you are using OpenCV's `png.h`, they raise an error if there is an alternative `png.h` already on your path.